# Describing something which exist in one month and doesn’t exist in the next!

Tags: word-request, word-in-context

I wanted to describe to my friend a situation where i wanted to mention that something exist in January, but doesn’t exist in February, exist in March, but not in April, exist in June but not in July, and so on.

How can I describe this in English using exact words. I tried to use **intervals** but i think it doesn’t work in this situation.

Comment: Try this one. It happens at regular intervals of each alternate month.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could say any of the following:

> X happens every other month.
>
> X takes place every other month, starting January.

From Cambridge:

> [every other something](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/every-other-something): not each one in a series, but every two.
>
> Example: The conference used to be held every year, but now it takes place every other year.
>   We get together every other Saturday for lunch.